# put string to length 20 (input and put function) sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to run the next code, because I need to put a string as char of length 20:

```
data input;
input str: $16.;
format str $16.;
datalines;
9224000007993931
9224000008225795
9033000008162048
9111000001835936
9999000000350632
;
run;

data transf;
set input;
n1=substr('00000000000000'||str,length('00000000000000'||str)-19,20);
n2 = put(input(str,20.), z20.);
run;
```

And then output is the next:

[image]

Why the last digit in n2 variable change for the first and second record?
n1 is the true result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a numeric precision issue. The maximum integer SAS can store exactly varies by OS; I’m guessing you’ve exceeded the limit. On windows, the maximum integer represented exactly is 2**53 = 9,007,199,254,740,992. You’re probably best off leaving this as a character value.  When you use input() to convert it to a numeric value, you can lose precision.